# Python KafkaConsumer not connecting

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, jupyter-notebook, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Setup:

I have 3 docker containers

```
1) For Kafka
2) For Zookeeper
3) For JupyterLab
```

I setup networking between these containers and I see that kafka producer is able to run and produce the data.

KafkaProducer.ipynb

```
KAFKA_BROKER = ['172.20.0.2:9093']
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=KAFKA_BROKER)

for _ in range(100):
    print("sending")
    producer.send('my-topic', key=b'foo', value=b'bar')
    print("success")
```

Here the send() sends message 100 times.

KafkaConsumer.ipynb

```
KAFKA_BROKER = ['172.20.0.2:9093']
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic',group_id='my-group',bootstrap_servers=KAFKA_BROKER)

print("Comm success")

for message in consumer:
    # message value and key are raw bytes -- decode if necessary!
    # e.g., for unicode: `message.value.decode('utf-8')`
    print ("%s:%d:%d: key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.partition,
                                          message.offset, message.key,
                                          message.value))
```

In the above consumer code the line `print("Comm success")` never gets gets executed. Based on producer code execution, the network is open and jupyter is able to talk to kafka broker. But, client is not able to connect to the same broker for data consumption. How can I start debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

By default `auto.offset.reset` value is `latest`, so set it to `earliest` with new group.id

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic',group_id='new-group',auto_offset_reset = 'earliest',bootstrap_servers=KAFKA_BROKER)
```